# how to render the same chart using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to add more chart on the div, I want to render more charts out at the same page using for loop or something. i can render charts using just paste another chart. but I want to render the more charts with using for loop or something in vanila javascript. i want to know if it's possible.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct01d.png)

Comment: yes its possible what did you try :-/

Comment: Looking at your image, I see what you are trying to achieve is to create multiple charts from the same data set. Is that correct? 
Please add some more details for your problem.

Comment: i did haha , I did it using copy and paste  i wanted to try doing it with for loop or something. I need to learn how to ask questions in here aha, sorry guys i should've put some details on it haha Thanks u guys  i hope u guys have a nice day !

Comment: Hi. It would be a good idea to provide an example of your code. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible, you can just call the new chart in a for loop, make sure to save the chart instances so you can work with them later

example:

```js
const charts = {
  options0: {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
          borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
          label: '# of Points',
          data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
          borderWidth: 1
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {}
  },
  options1: {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
          borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
          label: '# of Points',
          data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
          borderWidth: 1
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {}
  },
  options2: {
    type: 'radar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      datasets: [{
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
          borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
          label: '# of Points',
          data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
          borderWidth: 1
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {}
  }
}

let activeCharts = [];
for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(charts).length; i++) {
  activeCharts.push(new Chart(document.getElementById(`con${i}`).getContext('2d'), charts[`options${i}`]));
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="con0" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <canvas id="con1" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <canvas id="con2" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js" integrity="sha512-opXrgVcTHsEVdBUZqTPlW9S8+99hNbaHmXtAdXXc61OUU6gOII5ku/PzZFqexHXc3hnK8IrJKHo+T7O4GRIJcw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank u so much !! That's exactly what i have been looking for !!  I didn't know how to do that ! now i will be able to know how to do it  !! thank u so muchhhh 